# how can i fetch current date and time of my system in java without using any predefined classes or libraries?

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

how can i fetch current date and time of my system in java without using any predefined classes or libraries?
i am actually making a Date ADT of my own from scratch as java.util.Date or Java.util.Calendar. but i am not able to find out a way to fetch system date and time, say to calculate age of somebody if he enters his current age.
in a way i want to learn how they developers of Date or Calendar class actually implemented it. is there a way that i can see the code of Date and Calendar classes defined in java.util package.

Comment: The JDK source is available (with a specific licence), you can look at it all you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)**:

> Returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
>   midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

As for the source code of [`java.util.Date`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html) and [`java.util.Calendar`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html), you can either download the source directly from http://jdk7.java.net/source.html, or view it online in `docjar.com` or [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6).

Comment: i dont want to use any predefined function :/

Answer (score 3):

Well [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) isn't in `java.util` - is that what you were looking for? You'd then have to write the code to work out what that value (milliseconds since the unix epoch) means in terms of years etc - and you should consider the time zone and calendar system.

I would personally avoid trying to write your own date/time package unless it's just for fun. `java.util.Date` / `Calendar` are awful, but [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is much better, and there's the upcoming [JSR 310](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/).

> Is there a way that i can see the code of Date and Calendar classes defined in java.util package.

Sure - when you installed the JDK, you should have had the option of also installing a copy of the source code for the standard libraries, typically in `src.zip`. Alternatively, you could go to [openjdk.java.net](http://openjdk.java.net/) and look there.

> actually i don't want to use any predefined function at all.

Then you'd have to use [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) to get to an underlying system call, which seems pretty pointless to me - as it's basically what `System.currentTimeMillis` will do. That's fine if you're trying to learn JNI, but it's not really got much to do with date/time.

Of course if you're interested in an *accurate* time instead of the *system time, you could implement an [NTP](http://ntp.org/) client.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply
i am doing it just for fun! :D
just wanna learn how its done. actually i don't want to use any predefined function at all.

Comment: @RishkeshShukla: Well you'd have to use JNI then. How would you *expect* to get the system time without using *anything* from a system library?

Comment: Construction of an even half-decent date/time ADT like JODA will take _thousands_ of person-hours.  Have you seen some of the crazy edge cases there?